# Batch select and insert in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Hellos,
Can anyone help me look at this code; its generating an error."java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

//Code

```
private void btnBatchPayrollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "arrowsdb";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";
    try{
        Object newInstance = Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

   // int rows = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employeeinfo SELECT * FROM employeeinfo");
    //int rows = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO payroll(employeeid,fname,basic,housing,transport,medical) SELECT * FROM employeeinfo('EmployeeId','Name,Basic','Housing','Transport','Medical')");
    //INSERT INTO payroll (employeeid,fname,basic,housing,transport,medical) SELECT EmployeeId,Name,Basic,Housing,Transport,Medical FROM employeeinfo;
    int rows = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO payroll (employeeid,fname,basic,housing,transport,medical) SELECT EmployeeId,Name,Basic,Housing,Transport,Medical FROM employeeinfo;)");
    if (rows == 0) {
      System.out.println("Don't add any row!");
    } else {
      System.out.println(rows + " row(s)affected.");
      conn.close();
    }

    }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BatchPayroll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Thx
fm

Comment: Reformat your post please.

Comment: Long story short - your SQL is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra right parenthesis in your SQL.  I haven't tested this, because I don't have these SQL tables, but I think this is correct.  I used the MySQL 8 documentation to verify the format.

It also helps to format your code and SQL, so it's easier to spot errors like unbalanced parenthesis.

```
private void btnBatchPayrollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "arrowsdb";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Object newInstance = Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        // int rows = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employeeinfo SELECT * FROM
        // employeeinfo");
        // int rows = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO
        // payroll(employeeid,fname,basic,housing,transport,medical) SELECT * FROM
        // employeeinfo('EmployeeId','Name,Basic','Housing','Transport','Medical')");
        // INSERT INTO payroll (employeeid,fname,basic,housing,transport,medical) SELECT
        // EmployeeId,Name,Basic,Housing,Transport,Medical FROM employeeinfo;
        int rows = st.executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO payroll " +
                "   (employeeid, fname, basic, housing, transport, medical) " +
                "SELECT EmployeeId, Name, Basic, Housing, Transport, Medical " +
                "FROM employeeinfo; ");
        if (rows == 0) {
            System.out.println("Don't add any row!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(rows + " row(s)affected.");
            conn.close();
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BatchPayroll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```